# Can we hide row in win32 listview

Tags: c++, listview

I am using win32 listview control. My requirement is to hide a certain number of rows from listview but I could not find any flag by which I can hide the row item in listview.

I try creating a group and try hiding one the group but the LVGS_HIDDEN flag is not working as well.
I am looking at the documentation from below link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb774769(v=vs.85).aspx

Also If the hiding of the group is not working, it is possible to move row item from one group to another group.

Comment: There's a very simple way: you hide a row by removing it.  Separating the view from the model is a standard programming technique.

Answer (score 0):

The LVGS_HIDDEN flag will only be applied if LVGF_STATE is set.  An item's groupid can be changed by the [LVM_SETITEM message](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb761186%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).